# How can fix problem about exist query problem

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5, elk

There is a field with a nested type in an index and another field with a string type in this field. Any record has this field, but I would be very happy if you could help me to get count 0 when I query with exists.When I try it for any other nested field it works but not for one.

**my index mapping:**

```
 "MyFieldName1" : {
          "type" : "nested",
          "properties" : {
            "MyFieldName2" : {
              "type" : "keyword"
            },
            "MyFieldName3" : {
              "type" : "float"
            }
          }
        },
```

**My exists query:**

```
GET myindexname/_count
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "MyFieldName1",
      "query": {
        "exists": {
          "field": "MyFieldName1.MyFieldName2"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Result:
{
  "count" : 0,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  }
}
```

but I'm sure there is a document with this field.

Comment: Your requirement is not clear. Can you please explain this part of your question `If you could help me to get count 0 ` ?

Comment: Can you run the following and share whats the response?

GET /myindexname/_search {   "query": {
       "nested": {
         "path": "MyFieldName1",
         "query": {
             "bool": {
               "must": [
                   {
                     "exists": {
                         "field": "MyFieldName1.MyFieldName2"
                     }
                   }
               ]
             }
         }
     }   } }